# .Net Core API not receiving object in Post request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, post, axios

I have the following class / controller in my .Net Core API:

```
public class Tester
{
    public string Word1 { get; set; }
    public string Word2 { get; set; }
    public string Word3 { get; set; }
}

[Route("/users")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : AController<User, IUserRepository>
{

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("Test1")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test1([FromForm] Tester test)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

And in my React front-end I have the following code to Post to the API using Axios:

```
const sendToServer = () => {        
    const test = {Word1: "abc", Word2: "def", Word3: "ghi"};

    axios
        .post(
            '<my server>', 
            JSON.stringify(test), 
            {headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }}
        )
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result.data);
        })
    ;
}
```

And, when I run the function, my API action does get hit, but the `test` object is always empty (all 3 `Word` values are null).

I've tried to update the Post request in various ways such as:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("tester", {Word1: "abc", Word2: "def", Word3: "ghi"});

axios
    .post(
        '<my server>', 
        data, 
        {headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }}
    )
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data);
    })
;
```

or

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("tester", JSON.stringify({Word1: "abc", Word2: "def", Word3: "ghi"}));
```

But, every time, the `test` object doesn't get populated.

And, when I try and change the APi from `FromForm` to `FromBody`, it then never reaches the API and I get an error from the Axios post method:

```
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 415 
Remote Address: [::1]:5001
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

This is all very new to me, so I'm sure this is something stupid I am missing, but I have looked and can't find a solution that fixes this problem for me.

Comment: Maybe you should also set the content type of the request. Right now you are only setting the accept header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you sent a non-form body to the controller before. Now you are sending it without setting content type.

Add another header:

```
'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
```

You should be able to send data without stringify with axios. Try setting [FromBody] again and the request below

```
const sendToServer = () => {
    const test = { Word1: "abc", Word2: "def", Word3: "ghi" };

    axios
        .post(
            '<my server>',
            test,
            { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
        )
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result.data);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, John - I tried it and it changed my error code to `400`: `Status Code: 400`
`Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`. It's different, but still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: 400 sounds like the model isn't binding correctly. Can you set a breakpoint in the controller? Is run at all?

Comment: Yes, it runs. When I change it to `FromForm`, the action even gets hit and, when I set a breakpoint, that object is just all `null`s. When I change it to `FromBody`, I then get the 400 errors. This is driving me crazy and I don't know what to do to fix it!! :/!!!

Comment: see my updated answer and try that

Comment: **YOU GOT IT**!!! - The issue was with the `JSON.Stringify`!!!!!

Comment: As an aside, any logic about when to / not to use the `JSON.Stringify`?

Comment: I think axios serializes it as JSON per default so no need to do that. I wonder if it's only the JSON.stringify that was the problem or a combination of headers, stringify and the received type.

Comment: I can tell you that I had tried everything else and the thing that finally fixed it was removing the Stringify. Nonetheless, thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you send it in JSON, you should use `[FromBody]` attribute:

```cs
   public async Task<IActionResult> Test1([FromBody] Tester test)
```

`[FromForm]` is used, when object is sent as a form-data

Comment: I tried, but I get back a 415 (cross-origin) error from the server, then. (`Status Code: 415` 
`Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`). Is there an easy way to fix that / see if it works?

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: So it's still a CORS issue, darn it!!!????
I'm currently in testing and have this in my `StartUp`: `app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());` - I thought that would allow **ANYTHING** and let me test just the program for now :/

Comment: 415 isn't a cross origin error. Check my answer

Comment: Reading over it now. I just don't know what needs to be changed here, then. If you have a specific example, I'd REALLY appreciate it, otherwise, I'll keep reading and trying.